# Why is my CrossTable not square? gmodels package in R

Tags: r, classification

I don't how it could ever not be square, but here is my code.

It is making me type more, though I do not think there is anything else that makes sense to type.  It is missing the "-11" id column, but it is not missing the "-11" row.  It does not include the numbers from the "-11" column in the total column.  Though, as you can see, where the total row and total column intersect, the overall total is correct.

Any input would be appreciated.

(the csv is from https://www.kaggle.com/marianna13/starter-particle-identification-from-94dec2e4-9)

```
library(class)

library(tidyverse)

library(gmodels)

particle <- read_csv("C:/Users/laura_000/Documents/joe/ML with R/pid-5M.csv")

particles <- particle[sample(nrow(particle), 50000), ]

particles_train <- particles[1:45000, 2:7]
particles_test <- particles[45001:50000, 2:7]

particles_train_labels <- particles[1:45000, 1]
particles_test_labels <- particles[45001:50000, 1]


particles_test_pred <- knn(train = particles_train, test = particles_test, cl = particles_train_labels[,1, drop = TRUE], k = round(45000^.5))

CrossTable(x = particles_test_labels[,1, drop = TRUE], y = particles_test_pred, prop.chisq=FALSE)
```

Here's the output

```
   Cell Contents
|-------------------------|
|                       N |
|           N / Row Total |
|           N / Col Total |
|         N / Table Total |
|-------------------------|


Total Observations in Table:  5000 


                                        | particles_test_pred 
particles_test_labels[, 1, drop = TRUE] |       211 |       321 |      2212 | Row Total | 
----------------------------------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
                                    -11 |        20 |         0 |         0 |        20 | 
                                        |     1.000 |     0.000 |     0.000 |     0.004 | 
                                        |     0.007 |     0.000 |     0.000 |           | 
                                        |     0.004 |     0.000 |     0.000 |           | 
----------------------------------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
                                    211 |      2759 |         0 |        84 |      2843 | 
                                        |     0.970 |     0.000 |     0.030 |     0.569 | 
                                        |     0.901 |     0.000 |     0.044 |           | 
                                        |     0.552 |     0.000 |     0.017 |           | 
----------------------------------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
                                    321 |       181 |         8 |        44 |       233 | 
                                        |     0.777 |     0.034 |     0.189 |     0.047 | 
                                        |     0.059 |     1.000 |     0.023 |           | 
                                        |     0.036 |     0.002 |     0.009 |           | 
----------------------------------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
                                   2212 |       101 |         0 |      1803 |      1904 | 
                                        |     0.053 |     0.000 |     0.947 |     0.381 | 
                                        |     0.033 |     0.000 |     0.934 |           | 
                                        |     0.020 |     0.000 |     0.361 |           | 
----------------------------------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
                           Column Total |      3061 |         8 |      1931 |      5000 | 
                                        |     0.612 |     0.002 |     0.386 |           | 
----------------------------------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
```

Comment: It looks like the KNN model might never predict the `-11` class - it is the smallest class. You might have to decrease `k` in order for the model to have a better chance of predicting the less common classes.

Comment: @Marius  Thanks! That did the trick.  Apparently, it just leaves out the column of zeros.